# how to execute a query within a query?

Tags: php, mysql, select

After a query is done, on the basis of the result i want to make another result.how can i do that?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM programme";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{   
echo "$row[0]";
if($row[3]==1)
{
     $prgrmsql="SELECT MovieName FROM movie WHERE MovieId=".$row[1];
     $prgrmresult=mysql_query($prgrmsql);
     while($line=mysql_fetch_array($prgrmresult))
    {
          echo "$line[0]";
    }
    }
    else if($row[3]==2)
{
     $prgrmsql="SELECT SongsName FROM songs WHERE SongsId=".$row[1];
     $prgrmresult=mysql_query($prgrmsql);
     while($line=mysql_fetch_array($prgrmresult))
    {
          echo "$line[0]";
    }
    }           
}
```

but the query inside "if" is not executing.

This issue has been resolved

Comment: read about SQL joins.

Comment: did you check what's in `$row[3]`? If you have no records where it's 1 or 2, then neither of your if() clauses would execute.

Comment: can you give your table schema

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated. use http://us3.php.net/mysqli and in other news not every result has to be named $prgrmresult

Comment: hmmmm... he wants to select from two different tables... why you guys insist on join? of course it's possible to put a variable in place of the table name and use the same query, but still? why?

Comment: oh and op, you sure the condition for the if is actually true?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    /* inner function */
   SELECT /*something*/
   FROM table
)
```

Moreover, this can be expensive to do, so it's usually better to operate with a `JOIN`

```
/* example query */
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

For this specific question, it might be best to simply go with an `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM `programme`
INNER JOIN `movie`
ON `programme`.`/*row three*/` = 1
    AND `movie`.`MovieId` = `programme`.`/*first row*/`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit messed up with single and double quotes I think. your queries should go into double quotes, and variables into single ones. oh and you don't need double quotes around an array when you echo. here, first the query:

```
$prgrmsql = "SELECT MovieName FROM movie WHERE MovieId='$row[1]'";
```

it's the same for the second one. now for echo:

```
echo $row[0];
```

of course it works with the double quotes, because when presented with double quotes, the php interpretor will consider what's inside as code, but it serves no purpose to put it into double quotes.